# How to create interface for format JSON?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

How to create interface in TypeScript for this schema JSON:

```
{
  "1": [1,2,3],
  "55": [1,3,68]
}
```

I tried:

```
interface IJson {
  number: number[]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have key that is a string or a number as well to have the value of the map to be several type as well.

```
interface IJSON {
    [key: string]: (string | number)[];
    [index: number]: (string | number)[];
}
const test: IJSON = {
    "1": [1, 2, 3],
    "55": [1, 3, 68],
    525: [1, 3, 68],
}
```

If you want to have something more generic, you can use the generic for the type of value that the index holds.

```
interface IJSON2<TValue> {
    [key: string]: TValue[];
    [index: number]: TValue[];
}
const test2: IJSON2<number> = {
    "1": [1, 2, 3],
    "55": [1, 3, 68]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) here, since you're wanting a type that has arbitrary numeric keys. So that would look like:

```
interface IJson {
    [key: number]: number[];
}

// This assignment is okay:
const test: IJSON = {
    "1": [1, 2, 3],
    "55": [1, 3, 68],
}

// This is also okay and someValue is inferred to have type number[]
const someValue = test[1]

// But be careful, using this, only numbers can index the type:
// See the below note for how to allow string indices instead.
const otherValue = test["55"] // Error: Index expression is not of type number.
```

Note that you can also use a string for the index signature instead of number if that works better for your use case. Just replace `key: number` with `key: string` instead.

Comment: And how to initialize this? I did: `public obj: IJson = {};` then tried  `this.obj[key].push(value);` it can not insert value

Comment: An empty object `{}` has no keys to start with, so `this.obj[key]` is probably `undefined`. You'll have to check if it exists and set it to an empty array if it doesn't before you start pushing things to it. IE: `if (!this.obj[key]) this.obj[key] = []; this.obj[key].push(value)`.

Comment: So, key can be only numeric? not string? or can I set my custom type key?

Comment: The key can only be a string or a number (but not both). To make it a string, replace `key: number` with `key: string` in the type definition. You cannot set a custom key type (sadly).

Comment: So, I can not use this like Dictionary in C# with custom key type?

Comment: Correct, typescript only supports numbers and strings as a key type, nothing else.

Comment: And last remark how to set <T> type for property in class?

Comment: So, I mean this: `class MapClass<U> {
    public obj: <U> = {};}`

Comment: What is `U` supposed to be? The type of the field `obj` or the type of the values in `obj`? Does @PatrickDesjardins edit address that case?

Comment: `U` is custom type from Interface: `let mapClass = new MapClass<IJson>();`

Comment: Then you'll just use `U` in for anything that should be that type, no need for additional `<>`'s or anything. So: `class MapClass<U> { public obj: U = {} }` then `const myInstance = new myClass<IJson>()` would work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167903/discussion-between-crice-and-karabah).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no particular requirement about the number of elements in the arrays, you can use `type IJSON = Record<string, number[]>`. `Record` is a built-in type.